# Sorting a list using Composition of comparator

Tags: sorting, lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have been asked a question in interview where the requirement was to sort a list of Person using JAVA streams and comparator.

Given that, we have list of persons and multiple sort parameters in the input/
Sort parameters will be holding list of attribute name like personFirstName, personLastName and personAge.

I have written following program where I tried to create a composition of Comparator using "thenComparing"  method but it did not work.

```
package com.sample.streams.composition;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamComposition {

    class Person {
        private String personFirstName;

        private String personAge;

        private String personLastName;

        public Person(String personFirstName, String personAge, String personLastName) {
            super();
            this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
            this.personAge = personAge;
            this.personLastName = personLastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PersonFirstName : [" + personFirstName + "], PersonLastName : [" + personLastName
                    + "], PersonAge : [" + personAge + "]";
        }

        public String getPersonFirstName() {
            return personFirstName;
        }

        public void setPersonFirstName(String personFirstName) {
            this.personFirstName = personFirstName;
        }

        public String getPersonAge() {
            return personAge;
        }

        public void setPersonAge(String personAge) {
            this.personAge = personAge;
        }

        public String getPersonLastName() {
            return personLastName;
        }

        public void setPersonLastName(String personLastName) {
            this.personLastName = personLastName;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamComposition ob = new StreamComposition();
        Person p1 = ob.new Person("Gunjan", "30", "Shah");
        Person p2 = ob.new Person("Vimal", "36", "Panchal");
        Person p3 = ob.new Person("Pooja", "29", "Wadkar");
        Person p4 = ob.new Person("Pooja", "55", "Thomas");

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p3);
        list.add(p4);

        System.out.println("------------CASE 1----------------");
        List<String> sortBy = new ArrayList<>();
        sortBy.add("personFirstName");
        sortAndPrint_1(list, sortBy);
        sortAndPrint_2(list, sortBy);

        System.out.println("------------CASE 2----------------");
        sortBy.add("personAge");
        sortAndPrint_1(list, sortBy);
        sortAndPrint_2(list, sortBy);

        System.out.println("------------CASE 3----------------");
        sortBy.add("personLastName");
        sortAndPrint_1(list, sortBy);
        sortAndPrint_2(list, sortBy);


    }


    public static void sortAndPrint_1(List<Person> persons, List<String> sortBy) {
            System.out.println("Method : sortAndPrint_1");
            List sortedPersons = (List) persons
                                        .stream()
                                        .sorted( 
                                                sortBy
                                                .stream()
                                                .map( s -> Comparator.comparing(getFunction(s)))
                                                .reduce((c1,c2) -> c1.thenComparing(c2))
                                                .get())
                                        .collect( Collectors.toList());

            sortedPersons
                .stream()
                .forEach( p -> System.out.println(p));

    }

    public static void sortAndPrint_2(List<Person> persons, List<String> sortBy) {
        System.out.println("Method : sortAndPrint_2");
        sortBy
            .stream()
            .map( s -> Comparator.comparing(getFunction(s)))
            .forEach(c -> Collections.sort(persons,c));


        persons
            .stream()
            .forEach( p -> System.out.println(p));

    }



    public static Function getFunction(String param) {

        Function<Person,String> function = null;
        switch (param) {
        case "personFirstName" :
            function = (p) -> p.getPersonFirstName();
            break;
        case "personLastName" :
            function = (p) -> p.getPersonLastName();
            break;
        case "personAge" :
            function = (p) -> p.getPersonAge();
            break;
        }

        return function;
    }
}
```

And the output of above program is as below :

```
------------CASE 1----------------
Method : sortAndPrint_1
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
Method : sortAndPrint_2
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
------------CASE 2----------------
Method : sortAndPrint_1
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
Method : sortAndPrint_2
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
------------CASE 3----------------
Method : sortAndPrint_1
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
Method : sortAndPrint_2
PersonFirstName : [Vimal], PersonLastName : [Panchal], PersonAge : [36]
PersonFirstName : [Gunjan], PersonLastName : [Shah], PersonAge : [30]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Thomas], PersonAge : [55]
PersonFirstName : [Pooja], PersonLastName : [Wadkar], PersonAge : [29]
```

Here, I have created two methods **sortAndPrint_1** and **sortAndPrint_2**.
In method sortAndPrint_1, I have first created outer stream over person list and then I am trying to apply composition of comparators but it is not working.

So, I wrote another method **sortAndPrint_2** where I am  iterating over outer stream of **sortBy** and using **Collection.sort** method to sort the list. This method is sorting the records as expected after adding missing break statements in switch case.

Here, the aim of the program is to achieve multi level sorting.

I am still facing issues with method "sortAndPrint_1" which generates wrong output. I want the record first sorted on peronFirstName, then on personAge, then on personLastName.

Can someone please suggest me what is wrong with logic of "sortAndPrint_1" ? Is there any problem with the way I have used reduce method ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem - you have no duplicate first names so sorting by first name and _anything else_ will be exactly equivalent to sorting by first name alone...

Comment: @Boris the Spider, Inputs might vary here. We can also consider this example with duplicates names where multi level sorting makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in that code.

The main one is that there is not `break` after each case in the switch statement, so `getFunction()` always returns the last one, which returns the age.

Other issues include:

- using a String to represent an age (sorting by age will sort by alphabetical order of the string, rather than by numeric order)
- using raw types instead of properly-typed generics
- the sortAndPrint_2 method which only sorts by the last comparator
- not having the required test data in order to test the composition of comparators, since all properties are distinct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have added missing break statements and now sortAndPrint_2 method works fine. But sortAndPrint_1 is still not giving correct result.

Comment: No, sortAndPrint_2 can't run fine. It's broken. And regarding sortAndPrint_1, "not giving the correct result" is not relly helpful if you don't say what you expect as a result and what you get as a result.

Comment: @GunjanShah re `sortAndPrint_2` - this is a version of radix sort; it doesn't work because your values aren't "nested". If you wanted sort by first name, then - for each person - by their transaction time, for example, that would work. Radix sort is generally used to sort numbers.

Comment: How can it sort properly, but not give the correct output? Again, what do you expect to happen **precisely**, and what happens instead **precisely**? What is the actual output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Here I want to achieve multi level sorting. I want the records to be sorted as per the orders given in the input. That is firstName, Age and LastNAme. I am more interested on composition of comparators in method sortAndPrint_1. But also want to understand in details why did you say that method sortAndPrint_2 will also not work due to radix sort ? I think it is working fine as per the output posted in the questions.

Comment: Just read the code of sortAndPrint_2. It sorts the collection by first name. So the collection is now sorted by first name. Then it resorts the collection by age. So the collection is now sorted by age. Then it sorts it by lastName. That's not multi-level sorting. Multi-level sorting is what you're doing in the first method: compare by first name, then, **if two persons have the same first name**, compare them by age, then **if two persons have the same first name and the same age**, compare them by last name.

Comment: In precise terms, I want first sort the person list  as per the inputs "sortBy" and then print it. Here, sortAndPrint_1 is not working properly but sortAndPrint_2 is working fine as it is sorting the records based on firstName, age and lastName.

Comment: ahh..agree .. my understanding of multi level sorting was not correct. now understood the point. So, lets just concentrate on method sortAndPrint_1. How can we fix it ?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. It now works correctly (as long as you accept that ages are sorted alphabetically and not numerically). If you think it doesn't, explain why.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I tested it with more test cases.

Comment: Could you please add more details for sortAndPrint_2. Why it will not work. And I also tried to change the type of personAge to Integer. I change the method getFunction return type to Function<Person, ?>. So function can return either String or Integer. But I started getting compilation error on lambda expression. How can I pass a Function to comparing method whose return type might vary like String, Integer ?  Error is : The method comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Function<StreamComposition.Person,capture#4-of ?>)

Comment: @GunjanShah might I suggest you get some paper and a pencil then sort a list of people first **only** by last name and then **only** by first name. Are they still sorted by last name after this?

Comment: @Boris, Sorting the records only on lastName then again sorting only on firstName, will result the records sorted only on  firstName. We already reached to that points. My understanding about multi level sorting was not correct.

Comment: @GunjanShah so surely it's clear why `sortAndPrint_2` won't work?

Comment: @GunjanShah then why are you asking why your sortAndPrint_2 will not work? What it does is exactly what Boris said in his comment. Sort only on first name. Then re-sort only on age. Then re-sort only on last name.

Comment: Yes, it is clear now why sortAndPrint_2  will not work. Code of sortAndPrint_2  does not implement multi level sorting but it does sorting over sorting (resorting). So it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the points in [JB Nizet's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57344342/2071828)

```
static <T extends Person> Stream<T> sort(final Supplier<Stream<T>> input, final String... properties) {
    return input.get().sorted(compare(properties));
}

static Comparator<Person> compare(final String... properties) {
    return Arrays.stream(properties)
                  .map(TestBench::compare)
                  .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no properties specified"));
}

static Comparator<Person> compare(final String property) {
    switch (property) {
        case "firstName":
            return Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName);
        case "secondName":
            return Comparator.comparing(Person::getSecondName);
        case "age":
            return Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge);
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

static class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String secondName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(final String firstName, final String secondName, final int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    // toString, equals, hashCode etc
}
```

---

Usage

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<Person> people = List.of(
            new Person("Bob", "Smith", 29),
            new Person("Bob", "Smith", 30),
            new Person("James", "Smith", 31),
            new Person("Bob", "Jones", 52),
            new Person("James", "Jones", 71),
            new Person("Bob", "Anderson", 61),
            new Person("James", "Anderson", 32)
    );

    sort(people::stream, "firstName", "secondName")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output

```
Person{firstName='Bob', secondName='Anderson', age=61}
Person{firstName='Bob', secondName='Jones', age=52}
Person{firstName='Bob', secondName='Smith', age=29}
Person{firstName='Bob', secondName='Smith', age=30}
Person{firstName='James', secondName='Anderson', age=32}
Person{firstName='James', secondName='Jones', age=71}
Person{firstName='James', secondName='Smith', age=31
```

---

Personally I would rewrite this to use an `enum` so that it's typesafe

```
enum PersonProperty implements Comparator<Person> {
    FIRST_NAME(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName)),
    LAST_NAME(Comparator.comparing(Person::getSecondName)),
    AGE(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));

    final Comparator<Person> comparator;

    PersonProperty(final Comparator<Person> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final Person o1, final Person o2) {
        return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }

    public Comparator<Person> getComparator() {
        return comparator;
    }

    static Comparator<Person> compare(final PersonProperty... properties) {
        return Arrays.stream(properties)
                .map(PersonProperty::getComparator)
                .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no properties specified"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `.get()` on an `Optional` unconditionally, I’d use either, `.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no properties specified"))` or providing a fallback, `.orElse((a,b) -> 0)`, which would simply keep the list unchanged when no sort properties are given.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you defined have a List argument. Why? You could also have provided the method reference already. Or even used the API as is. There was no requirement to change the sorting by providing different arguments, right?

My version would also separate sorting and printing for readability and separation of concerns.

```
List<Person> sorted = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName).andThenBy(Person::getFirstName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I was trying to simulate the question which was asked during interview. so, just assume here, we have been given a list of Strings which defines sortBy parameter. And the list size may vary. It may have two params or three  params. So we need to create the required comparator at run time depending on list size

Comment: Also agree with second points, I should not use String to hold value of age. But I need a common method to provide Functions at runtime. How can I update getFunction method to provide functions with different returns types ?

Comment: Also agree with second points, I should not use String to hold value of age. But I need a common method to provide Functions at runtime. How can I update getFunction method to provide functions with different returns types ?

Comment: Then you can use the Function as used by Comparator.comparing, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function- for the exact generics supplied.